# Android - undefined reference to cryptopp

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, crypto++

I successfully compiled and executed Cryptopp in IOS but i really struggling to make work it in android.

Here i am using Cryptopp 5.6.3, NDK r10e and android studio 1.5 , I can successfully build libcryptopp.so through ndk-build but it throughs number of errors like undefined reference to 'vtable for CryptoPP::AutoSeededX917RNG' when i make rebuild through android studio.

**In Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := crypt_user
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := crypt_user.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := cryptopp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := cryptopp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libcryptopp.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**in Application.mk**

```
APP_ABI := armeabi
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions -frtti
APP_STL := stlport_shared
#APP_STL := gnustl_shared
```

**in build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kasbah.jeeva.ndklearning"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        ndk {
            moduleName = "crypt_user"
            cFlags("-fexceptions")
            stl = "stlport_shared"
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

**In crypt_user.cpp**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "../cryptopp/include/cryptlib.h"

#include "../cryptopp/include/osrng.h"
//using CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool;
using CryptoPP::AutoSeededX917RNG;

#include "../cryptopp/include/aes.h"
using CryptoPP::AES;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
jlong Java_com_kasbah_jeeva_ndklearning_MainActivity_fun
    (JNIEnv* env, jobject o, jint i) {

    AutoSeededX917RNG<AES> rng;

  long long t = CryptoPP::INFINITE_TIME / i;
  return t;
}
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I can compile it successfully when i didnt use any cryptopp related code.

Please help me to solve this problem because i am fighting with this for more than 2 weeks..

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> ... number of errors like undefined reference to `'vtable for CryptoPP::AutoSeededX917RNG'`

Use `nm` to ensure the symbol is present:

```
$ arm-linux-androideabi-nm -D --demangle libcryptopp.so | grep AutoSeededX917RNG | sed 's|CryptoPP::||g'
00181ec4 W AutoSeededX917RNG<Rijndael>::IncorporateEntropy(unsigned char const*, unsigned int)
0017d728 W AutoSeededX917RNG<Rijndael>::GenerateIntoBufferedTransformation(BufferedTransformation&, std::string const&, unsigned long long)
00181c18 W AutoSeededX917RNG<Rijndael>::Reseed(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*)
00181ddc W AutoSeededX917RNG<Rijndael>::Reseed(bool, unsigned char const*, unsigned int)
00181e80 W AutoSeededX917RNG<Rijndael>::AutoSeededX917RNG(bool, bool)
00181e80 W AutoSeededX917RNG<Rijndael>::AutoSeededX917RNG(bool, bool)
00169d90 W AutoSeededX917RNG<Rijndael>::~AutoSeededX917RNG()
00169d6c W AutoSeededX917RNG<Rijndael>::~AutoSeededX917RNG()
00169d6c W AutoSeededX917RNG<Rijndael>::~AutoSeededX917RNG()
0017d724 W AutoSeededX917RNG<Rijndael>::CanIncorporateEntropy() const
0023336c D typeinfo for AutoSeededX917RNG<Rijndael>
001fe0bc R typeinfo name for AutoSeededX917RNG<Rijndael>
00232308 V vtable for AutoSeededX917RNG<Rijndael>
```

---

> in Application.mk
>   ...

Below is what my `Android.mk` looks like for a shared object that provides random numbers. You can find it on GitHub at [Android-PRNG](https://github.com/noloader/Android-PRNG). Notice the STLport stuff is first, the Crypto++ stuff is second, and then the PRNG library is third.

The PRNG library is simple. It contains one file - `libprng.cpp`. It samples sensors to develop seeds for a random number generator. Android Java calls into the PRNG library.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# NDK_DEBUG_IMPORTS := 1

#########################################################
# STLport library
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

STLPORT_INCL     := /opt/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport
STLPORT_LIB      := /opt/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)

LOCAL_MODULE := stlport_shared
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(STLPORT_LIB)/libstlport_shared.so

LOCAL_EXPORT_CPPFLAGS :=
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(STLPORT_INCL)

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES  := stlport_shared

#########################################################
# Crypto++ library
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

CRYPTOPP_INCL   := /usr/local/cryptopp/android-$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/include
CRYPTOPP_LIB    := /usr/local/cryptopp/android-$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib

LOCAL_MODULE       := cryptopp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES    := $(CRYPTOPP_LIB)/libcryptopp.so

LOCAL_EXPORT_CPPFLAGS := -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(CRYPTOPP_INCL) $(CRYPTOPP_INCL)/cryptopp

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES  := cryptopp

#########################################################
# PRNG library
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

APP_STL         := stlport_shared
APP_MODULES     := prng stlport_shared cryptopp

# My ass... LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES is useless
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES   := $(STLPORT_INCL) $(CRYPTOPP_INCL)

LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES := rtti exceptions

LOCAL_CPP_FLAGS    := -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function
LOCAL_CPP_FLAGS    += -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL

LOCAL_LDLIBS            := -llog -landroid
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES  := cryptopp stlport_shared

LOCAL_MODULE    := prng
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libprng.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

---

The GitHub project builds fine using `ndk-build`:

```
~$ cd Android-PRNG
Android-PRNG$ ndk-build
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-14 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 9 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
[armeabi] Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.8] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
[armeabi] Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
[x86] Gdbserver      : [x86-4.8] libs/x86/gdbserver
[x86] Gdbsetup       : libs/x86/gdb.setup
[mips] Gdbserver      : [mipsel-linux-android-4.8] libs/mips/gdbserver
[mips] Gdbsetup       : libs/mips/gdb.setup
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.8] libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
[x86_64] Gdbserver      : [x86_64-4.9] libs/x86_64/gdbserver
[x86_64] Gdbsetup       : libs/x86_64/gdb.setup
[armeabi] Prebuilt       : libcryptopp.so <= /usr/local/cryptopp/android-armeabi/lib/
[armeabi] Install        : libcryptopp.so => libs/armeabi/libcryptopp.so
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: prng <= libprng.cpp
[armeabi] Prebuilt       : libstlport_shared.so <= /opt/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/libs/armeabi/
[armeabi] StaticLibrary  : libstdc++.a
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libprng.so
[armeabi] Install        : libprng.so => libs/armeabi/libprng.so
[armeabi] Install        : libstlport_shared.so => libs/armeabi/libstlport_shared.so
[x86] Prebuilt       : libcryptopp.so <= /usr/local/cryptopp/android-x86/lib/
[x86] Install        : libcryptopp.so => libs/x86/libcryptopp.so
[x86] Compile++      : prng <= libprng.cpp
[x86] Prebuilt       : libstlport_shared.so <= /opt/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/libs/x86/
[x86] StaticLibrary  : libstdc++.a
[x86] SharedLibrary  : libprng.so
[x86] Install        : libprng.so => libs/x86/libprng.so
[x86] Install        : libstlport_shared.so => libs/x86/libstlport_shared.so
[mips] Prebuilt       : libcryptopp.so <= /usr/local/cryptopp/android-mips/lib/
[mips] Install        : libcryptopp.so => libs/mips/libcryptopp.so
[mips] Compile++      : prng <= libprng.cpp
[mips] Prebuilt       : libstlport_shared.so <= /opt/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/libs/mips/
[mips] StaticLibrary  : libstdc++.a
[mips] SharedLibrary  : libprng.so
[mips] Install        : libprng.so => libs/mips/libprng.so
[mips] Install        : libstlport_shared.so => libs/mips/libstlport_shared.so
[armeabi-v7a] Prebuilt       : libcryptopp.so <= /usr/local/cryptopp/android-armeabi-v7a/lib/
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libcryptopp.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libcryptopp.so
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: prng <= libprng.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Prebuilt       : libstlport_shared.so <= /opt/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/libs/armeabi-v7a/
[armeabi-v7a] StaticLibrary  : libstdc++.a
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libprng.so
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libprng.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libprng.so
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libstlport_shared.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libstlport_shared.so
[x86_64] Prebuilt       : libcryptopp.so <= /usr/local/cryptopp/android-x86_64/lib/
[x86_64] Install        : libcryptopp.so => libs/x86_64/libcryptopp.so
[x86_64] Compile++      : prng <= libprng.cpp
[x86_64] Prebuilt       : libstlport_shared.so <= /opt/android-ndk-r10d/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/libs/x86_64/
[x86_64] StaticLibrary  : libstdc++.a
[x86_64] SharedLibrary  : libprng.so
[x86_64] Install        : libprng.so => libs/x86_64/libprng.so
[x86_64] Install        : libstlport_shared.so => libs/x86_64/libstlport_shared.so
```

Comment: I can successfully build it through ndk-build in terminal. But the problem what i am facing is its throws error when i try to build project ( Build->Rebuild)

Comment: @user1007302 - it would probably be a good idea to (1) state the exact step you are performing (and how you are performing it), and (2) state the exact error messages you are encountering. So far, this is about all the information you have provided us: *"...number of errors like undefined reference to {X}..."*. You can add the information to your question by clicking ***Edit***.